# Create method in endpoint class - Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to App Engine application development.I want to create custom method in my entity endpoint class. For that i am using `@ApiMethod` annotation to define custom method in endpoint class.The problem is that when i invoke this method from my android client it throws `IOException`. I don't know what is the problem with my code. Please guide me. 
Thank you.

Endpoint code :

```
@Api(name = "feedmasterendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "sampleregistrationapp.com", ownerName = "sampleregistrationapp.com", packagePath = ""))
public class FeedMasterEndpoint {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @ApiMethod(name = "getUserFeed", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
        public ArrayList<String> getUserFeed(@Named("userId_fk") String id) {
            EntityManager mgr = null;
            ArrayList<String> feedList = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                mgr = getEntityManager();
                Query query = mgr
                        .createQuery("select f.feedUrl from FeedMaster f where f.userId_fk= :userId");
                query.setParameter("userId", id);
                feedList = (ArrayList<String>) query.getResultList();
            } finally {
                mgr.close();
            }
            return feedList;
        }
}
```

Android client code:

```
StringCollection urlList = new StringCollection();
Feedmasterendpoint.Builder builder = new Feedmasterendpoint.Builder(
                        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                            public void initialize(HttpRequest arg0)
                                    throws IOException {

                            }
                        });

                Feedmasterendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                        builder).build();

                urlList = endpoint.getUserFeed(params[0]).execute(); //It throws IOException
```

Comment: I don't use endpoints so I cannot be sure, but aren't you meant to re-generate the client source code and then recompile it after you change your server API?

Comment: Yes i am generating client libraries from this endpoint class and recompiled my code hundred times but its not solving my problem.

Comment: yes, but what problem? IOException? but where does it come from? exception with stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of searching i got to know that might be there is no such facility to fetch particular column from Datastore of app engine and to solve that problem i fetched entire entity and it worked for me.